# What does the following notation mean?

Tags: estimation, notation

I have $(X_i, Y_i)$ as random vectors for $i=1,2,3,\dotsc, 10$. All $X_i$'s and $Y_i$'s are uniformly distributed. My question is about the definition of $R$ which is a random variable such that $R=1(X_i, Y_i)$. $(X_i, Y_i)$ here is a subscript of 1. I just do not know what 1 means. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense in the context of the problem I am working on. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the indicator function. A indicator function equals 1 when the condition is true, zero otherwise.

$$1_A =
  \begin{cases}
    1       & \quad \text{if } A \text{ is true}\\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise}\\
  \end{cases}
$$